# C# how to get process from all sessions

Tags: c#, .net

I am running code on Windows Server 2012 R2 where i have multiple sessions.

On each session there is few Notepad.exe opened with different window name.

How i can get a list of all Notepad.exe processes from all sessions so i can minimize window or close process for selected process from a list ?

I used this code, but it gives me only processes from current session where i am logged in.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        if (process.ProcessName == "notepad")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} - ID: {1} - Window title: {2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WTSEnumerateProcesses` (in it's various guises) is the right starting point, but I think you'll fall over if you're trying to get the window titles associated with those processes.

Comment: You can't manipulate windows in other sessions. You'd need to have copies of your process running in all those other sessions so they could act as your agents.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cassia/ Like the other comment says, you need session API (Terminal Services) to query that, and Cassia is a library wrapping over such. However, that requires administrator permissions usually.

Comment: @LexLi do you have any example how to use this package ?

Comment: @Sanja Ask Google, not me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue thanks to @Lex Li, used library from nuget.

I used this line `if (process.ProcessName == "notepad.exe" && session.SessionId == process.SessionId)` to extract only process name i need and match it to session.

```
   using Cassia;

    // call all process from sessions
    private void GetSessionsProcess()
    {
        ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
        ITerminalServer server = manager.GetLocalServer(); // server name
        server.Open();
        WriteProcesses(server.GetProcesses(), manager);
    }

    // get all process that is running in all sessions
    private void WriteProcesses(IEnumerable<ITerminalServicesProcess> processes, ITerminalServicesManager manager)
    {
        ITerminalServer server = manager.GetLocalServer();
        foreach (ITerminalServicesProcess process in processes)
        {
            foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
            {
                if (process.ProcessName == "notepad.exe" && session.SessionId == process.SessionId)
                {
                    PopulateTerminalsList(process.SessionId.ToString(), process.ProcessId.ToString(), process.ProcessName, session.UserAccount.ToString(), session.UserName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```